# Facebook SDK Error 'graph_domain' not found

Tags: unity

> using Facebook Unity SDK v7.19.0 with FBAndroidSDK/6.2.0

I am receiving a **Log Warning**

```
Did not find expected value 'graph_domain' in dictionary
```

What does this means? and how to handle it so that I can remove this warning.

Comment: Can you show us the callstack where this warning occurs?

Comment: @DMGregory using logcat Unity only gave me this


`Using Facebook Unity SDK v7.19.0 with FBAndroidSDK/6.2.0`
`(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 45)`


`Did not find expected value 'graph_domain' in dictionary`
`(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 45)`